# Extend Swatch rendered js file

Tags: javascript, requirejs, swatches, renderer

How to extend the Swatch rendered js file in my custom module?

I have override the phtml template files.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=swatch-option-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $productId ?>]": {
            "Custom_Swatch/js/swatch-renderer": {
                "selectorProduct": ".product-item-details",
                "onlySwatches": true,
                "enableControlLabel": false,
                "numberToShow": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getNumberSwatchesPerProduct(); ?>,
                "jsonConfig": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
                "jsonSwatchConfig": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
                "mediaCallback": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getMediaCallback() ?>",
                "flipImageAttribute": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $getFlipAttributeLabel ?>",
                "isFlipEnabled":"<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $isFlipEnabled ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have added Require JS file in that I have mapped my custom JS file like this -

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
              'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer':'Custom_Swatch/js/swatch-renderer'
        }
    }
};
```

After this I have copied the Swatch-renderer.js in the shared location and the file is working fine. But I only want the specific function in my file, and not all. And that is done by extended. I read that mixin does something like that but I am not sure on how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

This one is through mixin. 
Inside your requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
...
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
            'js/swatch-renderer-mixin': true    // Add your module name if not in theme's js folder.
        }
    }
}};
```

Next in js/swatch-renderer-mixin.js override widget and return same response as original

```
define(['jquery'],function ($) {
'use strict';

return function (widget) {
    $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', widget, {

    });   
    return $.mage.SwatchRenderer;
};
});
```

Here you can override methods, just call this._super to call parent

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way:

> custom_swatch/view/frontend/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable */ ?>
<div class="swatch-opt" data-role="swatch-options"></div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-role=swatch-options]": {
        "Custom_Swatch/js/swatch-renderer": {
            "selectorProduct": ".product-item-details",
            "onlySwatches": true,
            "enableControlLabel": false,
            "numberToShow": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getNumberSwatchesPerProduct(); ?>,
            "jsonConfig": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
            "jsonSwatchConfig": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
            "mediaCallback": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getMediaCallback() ?>",
            "flipImageAttribute": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $getFlipAttributeLabel ?>",
            "isFlipEnabled":"<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $isFlipEnabled ?>"
        }
    }
}
```

> /custom_swatch/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

```
/** make your edit **/
```

> custom_swatch/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable">
    <plugin name="updateBlockTemplate" type="Custom\Swatch\Plugin\Product\Renderer\ConfigurablePlugin" />
</type>
```

> Custom/Swatch/Plugin/Product/Renderer/ConfigurablePlugin

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Swatch\Plugin\Product\Renderer;

use Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable;

class ConfigurablePlugin
{
    public function beforeSetTemplate(Configurable $subject, $template) 
    {
        return ['Custom_Swatch::product/view/renderer.phtml'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain if I will delete the functions not needed from swatch-renderer.js how the file will work?