# Want to display price in configurable products each options in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, configurable-product-options

I want to display configurable products associated simple product price in configurable product option.

I am attaching image as price display below the option value. If some one has did this task then help me.

[image]

Comment: Follow this step and get the value from the swatch phtml
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261246/how-do-i-show-child-product-quantity-inside-a-config-grouped-product/261257#261257

Comment: I have tried to make changes in swatch.phtml file but from console I found config product option data update using Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js file. 
So, I need to make change in swatch-renderer.js
Thanks for you response :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally displayed price with configurable product option!!

I have debug the code and found configurable product swatch options come from below file.

```
vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
```

So, I have overwrite "swatch-renderer.js" file into my custom theme. So, custom them path would be.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
```

Please change name "Vendor" and "default" as per your theme name.

Now, I have debug the code of swatch-renderer.js file and found options value generate using "_RenderSwatchOptions" function. So, I have made below changes.

Change #1: "_RenderSwatchOptions" do not get data of $widget veriable. So, I have make below change.

Befor:

```
_RenderSwatchOptions: function (config, controlId)
```

After my change:

```
_RenderSwatchOptions: function (config, controlId, $widget)
```

Change #2: search with "_RenderSwatchOptions" and change argument from where this function call from "swatch-renderer.js" file

Before:

```
options = $widget._RenderSwatchOptions(item, controlLabelId),
```

After my change:

```
options = $widget._RenderSwatchOptions(item, controlLabelId, $widget),
```

Change #3: Now I can get the value of $widget object in to "_RenderSwatchOptions" function but not abel to get price value of options.

So, to add option id wise price please add below code below the line change which applied in #2.

Before:

```
var item = this,
controlLabelId = 'option-label-' + item.code + '-' + item.id,
options = $widget._RenderSwatchOptions(item, controlLabelId),
```

After my change:

```
var item = this;

$widget.optionsMap[item.id] = {};

// Aggregate options array to hash (key => value)
$.each(item.options, function () {
    if (this.products.length > 0) {
        $widget.optionsMap[item.id][this.id] = {
            price: parseInt(
                $widget.options.jsonConfig.optionPrices[this.products[0]].finalPrice.amount,
                10
            ),
            products: this.products
        };
    }
});

 var controlLabelId = 'option-label-' + item.code + '-' + item.id,
 options = $widget._RenderSwatchOptions(item, controlLabelId, $widget),
```

Change #4: Add price div into "_RenderSwatchOptions" function.

My attribute is swatch options with type = text. So, I made below changes.

Before:

```
if (type === 0) {
    // Text
    html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' text" ' + attr + '>' + (value ? value : label) +    
        '</div>';
}
```

After my change:

```
if (type === 0) {
    // Text
    html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' text" ' + attr + '>' + (value ? value : label) +
    '<div class="custom-option-price">' + $widget.optionsMap[config.id][id]['price'] + '</div>'+
        '</div>';
}
```

Might be my post help someone who want to make change in configurable products options.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Darshan modi, your answer is very helpful, How to add custom attribute value next to price?

Comment: Thanks for sharing. And if you don't want to copy the entire swatch-renders.js you could just extend the widget with your modification on the _RenderControls() & _RenderSwatchOptions(). [https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/296050/56025](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/296050/56025)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Darshan + urbansurfers answers, I've placed this all into a mixin and also added the same feature to the `RenderSwatchSelect` function. I'll put it here in case anyone needs it:

`vendor/theme/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
                'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Darshan's answer seemed to be returning the prices incorrectly (it was rounded numbers - there's probably a reason why so I'm sorry) - so I just included the priceUtils library when i called the function and used that.

`vendor/theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'priceUtils'
], function ($,priceUtils) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', widget, {


            _RenderControls: function () {
                var $widget = this,
                    container = this.element,
                    classes = this.options.classes,
                    chooseText = this.options.jsonConfig.chooseText,
                    showTooltip = this.options.showTooltip;

                $widget.optionsMap = {};

                $.each(this.options.jsonConfig.attributes, function () {
                    var item = this;
                    $widget.optionsMap[item.id] = {};

                    // Aggregate options array to hash (key => value)
                    $.each(item.options, function () {
                        if (this.products.length > 0) {
                            $widget.optionsMap[item.id][this.id] = {
                                 price: priceUtils.formatPrice(
                                    $widget.options.jsonConfig.optionPrices[this.products[0]].finalPrice.amount,
                                    {},
                                    false
                                ),
                                products: this.products
                            };
                        }
                    });
                    var controlLabelId = 'option-label-' + item.code + '-' + item.id,
                    options = $widget._RenderSwatchOptions(item, controlLabelId, $widget),
                    select = $widget._RenderSwatchSelect(item, chooseText, $widget),
                    input = $widget._RenderFormInput(item),
                    listLabel = '',
                    label = '';

                    // Show only swatch controls
                    if ($widget.options.onlySwatches && !$widget.options.jsonSwatchConfig.hasOwnProperty(item.id)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if ($widget.options.enableControlLabel) {
                        label +=
                            '<span id="' + controlLabelId + '" class="' + classes.attributeLabelClass + '">' +
                            $('<i></i>').text(item.label).html() +
                            '</span>' +
                            '<span class="' + classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass + '"></span>';
                    }

                    if ($widget.inProductList) {
                        $widget.productForm.append(input);
                        input = '';
                        listLabel = 'aria-label="' + $('<i></i>').text(item.label).html() + '"';
                    } else {
                        listLabel = 'aria-labelledby="' + controlLabelId + '"';
                    }

                    // Create new control
                    container.append(
                        '<div class="' + classes.attributeClass + ' ' + item.code + '" ' +
                        'attribute-code="' + item.code + '" ' +
                        'attribute-id="' + item.id + '">' +
                        label +
                        '<div aria-activedescendant="" ' +
                        'tabindex="0" ' +
                        'aria-invalid="false" ' +
                        'aria-required="true" ' +
                        'role="listbox" ' + listLabel +
                        'class="' + classes.attributeOptionsWrapper + ' clearfix">' +
                        options + select +
                        '</div>' + input +
                        '</div>'
                    );

                    $widget.optionsMap[item.id] = {};

                    // Aggregate options array to hash (key => value)
                    $.each(item.options, function () {
                        if (this.products.length > 0) {
                            $widget.optionsMap[item.id][this.id] = {
                                price: parseInt(
                                    $widget.options.jsonConfig.optionPrices[this.products[0]].finalPrice.amount,
                                    10
                                ),
                                products: this.products
                            };
                        }
                    });
                });

                if (showTooltip === 1) {
                    // Connect Tooltip
                    container
                        .find('[option-type="1"], [option-type="2"], [option-type="0"], [option-type="3"]')
                        .SwatchRendererTooltip();
                }

                // Hide all elements below more button
                $('.' + classes.moreButton).nextAll().hide();

                // Handle events like click or change
                $widget._EventListener();

                // Rewind options
                $widget._Rewind(container);

                //Emulate click on all swatches from Request
                $widget._EmulateSelected($.parseQuery());
                $widget._EmulateSelected($widget._getSelectedAttributes());
            },

            _RenderSwatchOptions: function (config, controlId, $widget) {
                var optionConfig = this.options.jsonSwatchConfig[config.id],
                    optionClass = this.options.classes.optionClass,
                    sizeConfig = this.options.jsonSwatchImageSizeConfig,
                    moreLimit = parseInt(this.options.numberToShow, 10),
                    moreClass = this.options.classes.moreButton,
                    moreText = this.options.moreButtonText,
                    countAttributes = 0,
                    html = '';

                if (!this.options.jsonSwatchConfig.hasOwnProperty(config.id)) {
                    return '';
                }

                $.each(config.options, function (index) {
                    var id,
                        type,
                        value,
                        thumb,
                        label,
                        width,
                        height,
                        attr,
                        swatchImageWidth,
                        swatchImageHeight;

                    if (!optionConfig.hasOwnProperty(this.id)) {
                        return '';
                    }

                    // Add more button
                    if (moreLimit === countAttributes++) {
                        html += '<a href="#" class="' + moreClass + '"><span>' + moreText + '</span></a>';
                    }

                    id = this.id;
                    type = parseInt(optionConfig[id].type, 10);
                    value = optionConfig[id].hasOwnProperty('value') ?
                        $('<i></i>').text(optionConfig[id].value).html() : '';
                    thumb = optionConfig[id].hasOwnProperty('thumb') ? optionConfig[id].thumb : '';
                    width = _.has(sizeConfig, 'swatchThumb') ? sizeConfig.swatchThumb.width : 110;
                    height = _.has(sizeConfig, 'swatchThumb') ? sizeConfig.swatchThumb.height : 90;
                    label = this.label ? $('<i></i>').text(this.label).html() : '';
                    attr =
                        ' id="' + controlId + '-item-' + id + '"' +
                        ' index="' + index + '"' +
                        ' aria-checked="false"' +
                        ' aria-describedby="' + controlId + '"' +
                        ' tabindex="0"' +
                        ' option-type="' + type + '"' +
                        ' option-id="' + id + '"' +
                        ' option-label="' + label + '"' +
                        ' aria-label="' + label + '"' +
                        ' option-tooltip-thumb="' + thumb + '"' +
                        ' option-tooltip-value="' + value + '"' +
                        ' role="option"' +
                        ' thumb-width="' + width + '"' +
                        ' thumb-height="' + height + '"';

                    swatchImageWidth = _.has(sizeConfig, 'swatchImage') ? sizeConfig.swatchImage.width : 30;
                    swatchImageHeight = _.has(sizeConfig, 'swatchImage') ? sizeConfig.swatchImage.height : 20;

                    if (!this.hasOwnProperty('products') || this.products.length <= 0) {
                        attr += ' option-empty="true"';
                    }

                    if (type === 0) {
                        // Text
                        html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' text" ' + attr + '>' + (value ? value : label) +
                            '<div class="custom-option-price">' + $widget.optionsMap[config.id][id]['price'] + '</div>'+
                            '</div>';
                    } else if (type === 1) {
                        // Color
                        html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' color" ' + attr +
                            ' style="background: ' + value +
                            ' no-repeat center; background-size: initial;">' + $widget.optionsMap[config.id][id]['price'] +
                            '</div>';
                    } else if (type === 2) {
                        // Image
                        html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' image" ' + attr +
                            ' style="background: url(' + value + ') no-repeat center; background-size: initial;width:' +
                            swatchImageWidth + 'px; height:' + swatchImageHeight + 'px">' + '' +
                            '</div>';
                    } else if (type === 3) {
                        // Clear
                        html += '<div class="' + optionClass + '" ' + attr + '></div>';
                    } else {
                        // Default
                        html += '<div class="' + optionClass + '" ' + attr + '>' + label + '</div>';
                    }
                });

                return html;
            },

            _RenderSwatchSelect: function (config, chooseText, $widget) {
                var html;

                if (this.options.jsonSwatchConfig.hasOwnProperty(config.id)) {
                    return '';
                }

                html =
                    '<select class="' + this.options.classes.selectClass + ' ' + config.code + '">' +
                    '<option value="0" option-id="0">' + chooseText + '</option>';

                $.each(config.options, function () {

                    var label = this.label,
                        id = this.id,
                        attr = ' value="' + this.id + '" option-id="' + this.id + '"';

                    if (!this.hasOwnProperty('products') || this.products.length <= 0) {
                        attr += ' option-empty="true"';
                    }
                    html += '<option ' + attr + '>' + label + $widget.optionsMap[config.id][id]['price'] + '</option>';
                });

                html += '</select>';

                return html;
            }
        });

        return $.mage.SwatchRenderer;
    }
});
```

It might not be perfect. There's probably a lot of wool you need to shave off this sheep, but documentation on this is very very slim, so I hope I can save someone some time (like I needed!)