How to Override the swatch-renderer.js in Magento 2 Custom Theme?
I am trying to override the swatch-renderer.js file in my custom Magento 2 theme. I have created the required directories and the custom JavaScript file but it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have done so far:

Created the directory structure:
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

Copied the original swatch-renderer.js to this directory and made my changes.

Updated the requirejs-config.js in my theme as follows:


var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': 'js/custom-swatch-renderer'
        }
    }
};

But the changes do not seem to reflect on the frontend. Can anyone help me identify what I might be doing wrong? Thank you.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246256/extend-swatch-rendered-js-file

check this one.

To override the Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js file in a custom theme in Magento 2, follow these steps:
Step 1: Create the Required Directory Structure
In your custom theme, create the necessary directory structure to place your override file. Assuming your theme is located at app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme], the structure would be:
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Swatches/web/js/

Step 2: Copy the Original File to Your Theme
Copy the original swatch-renderer.js file from the Magento core module to your custom theme.

Source file (Magento core):
vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js


Destination in your custom theme:
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js



Step 3: Modify the JavaScript File
Now that the file is in your theme, you can edit swatch-renderer.js as needed. Make your customizations directly in this file.
Step 4: Clear Cache and Deploy Static Content
After making your changes, clear the cache and redeploy the static content:
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Step 5: Verify the Changes
After clearing the cache and deploying static content, check the frontend of your store to ensure that your changes to the swatch-renderer.js file are taking effect.
Summary

Path to Override: app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
Clear Cache and Deploy: Always flush cache and redeploy static content after making changes.

This method ensures that your customizations are applied and won't be overwritten by future Magento updates, as they reside within your custom theme.

as the requirejs-config.js file is in theme folder, Try updating the path to include the folder name.
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': 'Magento_Swatches/js/custom-swatch-renderer'
        }
    }
};


Setting Up The Directory Structure
1- Navigate your topic listing:
    app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/

2- create the following sub directories, if doesn't exist:
    Magento_Swatches/net/js/

3- Copy the authentic swatch-renderer.Js record from the Magento module on your topic’s/theme’s directory:
    Cp seller/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/internet/js/swatch-renderer.Js app/layout/frontend/Vendor/subject matter/Magento_Swatches/net/js/

Once you have copied the authentic document on your subject matter’s listing, you may begin making your customizations.
Updating requirejs-config.Js
1- Navigate on your subject listing
app/layout/frontend/Vendor/subject/

2- Open/create requirejs-config.Js in the following route:
app/layout/frontend/Vendor/subject matter/requirejs-config.Js

3-  Add the trails configuration to map the unique record for your custom file:
var config = {
map: {
'*': {
'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': 'Vendor_ThemeName/Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer'
}
}
};
Run the static content material command:
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Clean cache:
bin/magento cache:clean
